# How to store []byte as binary in MongoDB using go mongo-driver

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I'm using `using go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo` and I'm trying to story byte slice in MongoDB. However, the driver marshals it as an array of integers.

In my case I have the following type:

```golang
type Hash [20]byte
```

I tried to implement the `ValueMarshaler` interface as the foollowing:

```golang
func (h Hash) MarshalBSONValue() (bsontype.Type, []byte, error) {
    return bsontype.Binary, h[:20], nil
}
```

But it is clear that `h[:20]` does not return valid bytes for mongo. It panics and returns the following:

```
panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range [:-658764325]

goroutine 39 [running]:
go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/bsonx/bsoncore.ReadElement(0xc0004bca1c, 0x1d, 0xe4, 0x55b6910, 0xffffffffffffff01, 0xc000178d00, 0xc00129aa18, 0x406d52d, 0x4819ea0, 0xc000bba240)
       /go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.0.1/x/bsonx/bsoncore/bsoncore.go:122 +0x271
go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/bsonx/bsoncore.Document.Validate(0xc0004bca18, 0x21, 0xe8, 0x4799100, 0x26)
       /go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.0.1/x/bsonx/bsoncore/document.go:377 +0xe4
go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/bsonx.(*Doc).UnmarshalBSON(0xc00129aba0, 0xc0004bca18, 0x21, 0xe8, 0x5, 0xc00129abc8)
       /go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.0.1/x/bsonx/document.go:225 +0x6e
go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/bsonx.ReadDoc(0xc0004bca18, 0x21, 0xe8, 0xc0004bca18, 0x21, 0xe8, 0xc0004bca39, 0x0)
       /go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.0.1/x/bsonx/document.go:54 +0x77
go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/bsonx.(*Val).UnmarshalBSONValue(0xc00129b2c0, 0x3, 0xc0004bca18, 0x21, 0xe8, 0x21, 0xe8)
       /go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.0.1/x/bsonx/value.go:249 +0x90f
go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/bsonx.(*Doc).UnmarshalBSON(0xc00129b370, 0xc0004bca0a, 0x30, 0xf6, 0x44747df, 0xc0000b21e0)
       /go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.0.1/x/bsonx/document.go:236 +0x173
go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/bsonx.ReadDoc(0xc0004bca0a, 0x30, 0xf6, 0xc0004bca0a, 0x30, 0xf6, 0xc0004bca3a, 0x0)
       /go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.0.1/x/bsonx/document.go:54 +0x77
go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/bsonx.(*Val).UnmarshalBSONValue(0xc00129ba90, 0x3, 0xc0004bca0a, 0x30, 0xf6, 0x30, 0xf6)
       /go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.0.1/x/bsonx/value.go:249 +0x90f
go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/bsonx.(*Doc).UnmarshalBSON(0xc00129bb40, 0xc0004bca00, 0x3b, 0x100, 0xc0000b21e0, 0x100)
       /go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.0.1/x/bsonx/document.go:236 +0x173
go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/bsonx.ReadDoc(0xc0004bca00, 0x3b, 0x100, 0x0, 0x100, 0x4833880, 0xc000bba090, 0xc0004bca00)
       /go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.0.1/x/bsonx/document.go:54 +0x77
go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo.transformDocument(0xc00014a070, 0x4833880, 0xc000bba090, 0xc000bba120, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
       /go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.0.1/mongo/mongo.go:155 +0x1f5
go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo.(*Collection).UpdateOne(0xc00010e1e0, 0x4cca0a0, 0xc00010e3c0, 0x4833880, 0xc000bba060, 0x4833880, 0xc000bba090, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
       /go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.0.1/mongo/collection.go:530 +0xf0


Process finished with exit code 2
```

Answer (score 2):

BSON is a binary JSON. JSON per se doesn't have the byte array type, but it does have arrays.

The library can handle types without any additional marshallers.

Here is a minimal working example.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

type Hash [4]byte

type Model struct {
    Key Hash `bson:"key"`
}

func main() {
    client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 20*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    err = client.Connect(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    db := client.Database("database")
    collection := db.Collection("collection")

    // insert as plain []byte slice
    _, err = collection.InsertOne(ctx, bson.M{"key": [4]byte{1, 2, 3, 4}})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // insert h as a Hash type
    h := Hash([4]byte{1, 2, 3, 4})
    _, err = collection.InsertOne(ctx, bson.M{"key": h})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    cursor, err := collection.Find(ctx, bson.M{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var all []Model
    if err := cursor.All(ctx, &all); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(all)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm already doing this, however, this leads to having the []byte stored in the database as an Array of int32.

Comment: Saving bytes as int32 isn't that bad. You could potentially save a few bytes by packing every four bytes into int32 on marshal and reversing that on unmarshal. Though this approach has its downsides. First is maintaining the code. Second, the data is serialized and it is harder to edit directly if anything. To me, the gain here is questionable.

Comment: You can store more than 53 million of `Hash`'es you have that would fit into 1 GiB. Consider that before trying to improve storage schema.